# Shouldn't i cast Linq To Sql entity table to its real type?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

When i call "f_CategoriNewsGet" function from Page_Load method I'm getting null. But i can see tblNewsler object is full with objects before return line.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tblNewsler = News.f_CategoriNewsGet("ÇEVRE", 18); // return object is always
    Table<News> tblNewsler1 = tblNews;
    rptNatureNews.DataSource = tblNews != null ? tblNews.Take(6) : null;
    rptNatureNews.DataBind();
}

static public Table<News> f_CategoriNewsGet(string _sCategoriName, int _iTop)
{
    var tblNews = (from news in DAO.context.GetTable<News>()
                       join kategori in DAO.context.GetTable<NewsCategori>() on                                news.M_RefNewsCategoriId equals kategori.M_NewsCategoriId
                       where kategori.M_Adi.Equals(_sCategoriName)
                       orderby news.M_InsertDate descending
                       select news).Take(_iTop);
    return tblNews as Table<News>;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tblNews is **not** a `Table<News>`.  It is only an `IQueryable<News>`.  `context.GetTable<News>` *was*  a `Table<News>`, but applying query operators results in a different type -- the result of the query operator is no longer a `Table<T>`, but a (possibly internal) LINQ to SQL type representing the query.

Answer (score 0):

You got a bug here:

```
Table<News> tblNewsler1 = tblNews;
```

Should Be

```
Table<News> tblNewsler1 =  tblNewsler;
```